# How can I find an object in MongoDB by a match in the array of this object?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have documents by type:

```json
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"5fa6cdf065249ffc1282e880"},   
  "ask":["java",  
       "what is java",  
       "java is"],  
  "answer":"Java is a class-based, object-oriented programming language that is designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible"
}
```

How do I get a document by value in an array?

For example, I am writing "java is" and I want to get this document, but "java is" is in an array.

I easily received documents when the " ask " field was a String:

```java
@Repository   
public interface PostRepository extends MongoRepository<Answer, String> {  
  public Answer findAnswerByAsk(String ask);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need this query

```js
db.collection.find({
  "ask": "java is"
})
```

It will get the document that contains 'java is' into `ask` field.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HAcvYIn__OJ)

Using `Spring Boot` I can't test but using `@Query` should work.

Something like this (I repeat, not tested):

```java
@Query("{ 'ask': ?0}")
public Answer findAnswerByAsk(String ask);
```

Comment: Good bro! That's exactly what I wanted to decide. And it's not a bad resource that you gave me. Tell me if there are any good tutorials about what to specify in brackets @Query?

Comment: Baeldung has multiple guides. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb) explain the `@Query` annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Using Spring data mongodb repository you can search for element in collection using  `Containing` keyword. [Reference documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries)

```
@Repository   
public interface PostRepository extends MongoRepository<Answer, String> {  
  public Answer findAnswerByAskContaining(String ask);  
}
```

Using `mongoTemplate` helper you could use $elemMatch

```
Query query = new Query();      
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("ask").elemMatch(Criteria.is("java is"));
mongoTemplate.find(query, Document.class);
```